# Google Maps - Placing markers from an SQL database (XML, PHP)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

I'm working through this tutorial from Google https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 to use it for my own web application and I'm running into some problems.

First, I have created a form that accesses a PHP file to write to my SQL database and it shows that everything is running smoothly.  It connects properly and fills in the table as expected.

Second, using the tutorial above, I have managed to create a PHP file that generates correct XML.

Third, I've created a blank form with a button that runs a mapload() function when clicked.. which is supposed to do the following:  initialize the map, run through the xml file, and plot the points.

The map initialized correctly when the button is clicked, but for some reason it's not plotting the points.  So, I'm gathering that there's an error in my javascript somewhere.  Can anyone diagnose and solve the problem?  Here's the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>My Application</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my-  key&sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#map").click(function(){
    $("#mapcontainer").slideToggle("slow");
    });  
});

//<![CDATA[

function mapload() {

var mapstyle = [{featureType: "administrative",stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]},
    {featureType: "poi",stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]},
    {featureType: "transit",stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]},
    {featureType: "water",elementType: "geometry",stylers: [{ visibility: "simplified" },{ hue: "#1c252f" },{ saturation: "-55" },{lightness: "0" }]},
    {featureType: "water",elementType: "labels",stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]},
    {featureType: "poi.park",elementType: "geometry",stylers: [{ visibility: "simplified" },{ hue: "1c2f22" },{ saturation: "-55" },{ lightness: "15" }]},
    {featureType: "poi.park",elementType: "labels",stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }]},
    {featureType: "road",elementType: "geometry",stylers: [{ visibility: "simplified" },{ saturation: 42 },{ hue: "#ffa200" },{ lightness: 33 }]},
    {featureType: "road",elementType: "labels",stylers: [{ hue: "#0019ff" },{ lightness: 51 },{ saturation: -88 }]}
]

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(20,0),
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    styles: mapstyle
});

var InfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

downloadUrl ("mapexpand.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var id = markers[i] .getAttribute("id");
        var name = markers[i] .getAttribute("marker");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i] .getAttribute("Lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i] .getAttribute("Lng")));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> </br/>" + address;
        var markericon ='images/markericon.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: markericon
        });
    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, InfoWindow, html);
    }
});
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, wishWindow, html){
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

function downloadUrl (url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject ('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
        }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.sent(null);

}

function doNothing() {}

//]]>

</script>

</head>

<body onload='getLocation()'>



<div id="graphic"></div>
<div id="textbox"></div>


     <form action="store.php" method="post">

            <textarea cols="37" rows="7" autofocus maxlength="255" name="text"></textarea>
            <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="latitude">
            <input type="hidden" id="long" name="longitude">
            <input type="submit" id ="sub" name="submit">

     </form>

<div id="mapcontainer">


</div>

    <form>

        <input type="button" id="map" class="mapexpand" onClick="mapload()"></input>

    </form>

     <script>

     var lat=document.getElementById("lat");
     var long=document.getElementById("long");

     function getLocation() {

         if (navigator.geolocation){
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
         }
    }

     function showPosition(position) {
         lat.value=+position.coords.latitude;
         long.value=+position.coords.longitude;
     }


 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

XML:  Output  - lat and long removed for privacy, but outputs correct data.

```
<markers>
<marker marker="sweettttt" latitude="(lat removed)" longitude="(lng removed)"/>
</markers>
```

Comment: the site is on a localhost and i have no place to put it at the moment.

Comment: Try using a free site. It is far easier to debug a live site.especially return from mapexpand.php

Comment: mapexpand.php creates proper xml, similar to what's in the google tutorial listed above in my question.  i'll add the xml output from mapexpand.php to the main question

Comment: loading code onto my editor      <body onload='getLocation()'> but no function getLocation() Found it!!!

Comment: for some reason getLocation() only works when i include it into the body of my html.  however, the locations don't seem to be the problem.  added the one line of xml output to the main question

Comment: funny thing:  if i use the code directly from the google tutorial, it doesn't seem to add markers either.

Comment: see http://gleniffersystems.net46.net/maps/viewmarkers.html for demo using code

Comment: it appears that the code is the same, except for a few minor changes that won't affect the markers.

Comment: Ensure the path to  images/markericon.png is correct. As no marker will show if it is wrong Email me @ daviestrachan@yahoo.co.uk as the discussion is getting extended and you cant access chat

Comment: david - i've mostly figured it out.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the path to `images/markericon.png` is correct. As no marker will show if the path is wrong.

Comment: my xml variable was returning (null)  made some adjustments, it's working fine now.